# При слиянии ветки не обязательно указывать no-ff если оно нужно?

Tags: git, git-merge

Во всяких интернетах (в т.ч. на английском SO) пестрят картинки, что  если мы хотим сохранить историю коммитов ветки, которую вливаем и не переводить указатель чисто вперёд, то нужно ставить `--no-ff`.

Типичные картинки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако [тут](https://rtfm.co.ua/git-merge-zachem-nuzhna-opciya-no-ff-no-fast-forward/) говорится о том, что если в ветке уже были коммиты, то `--no-ff` в любом случае будет происходить

> Теперь изменения бранча testbranch идут в отдельной ветке даже без указания no fast-forward.

Вопрос вполне логичный и простой:

В итоге, если я нахожусь в какой-то ветке и нужно слить другую и чтобы коммиты сделанные в другой ветке согласно истории принадлежали именно второй, то если я уже делал коммиты в первой, то указывать `--no-ff` не обязательно?

А если я нахожусь на ветке `test1` сливаю себе `dev`, чтобы обновить данные, делаю ещё небольшую правку, коммит, пуш, а потом перехожу на `dev` и вливаю себе эту ветку `test1` то тоже уже не надо указывать флаг `--no-ff`?

Мне важна история всегда. Важно чтобы коммиты отображались именно на тех ветках, где были сделаны, а не шли в одной ветке, как прямая дорога.

Comment: Не обязательно, но указание `--no-ff` всегда позволяет не думать были или нет изменения в dev-ветке после форка фиче-ветки.

Comment: Это дискуссия о вкусе ананасов для человека А и человека Б. Как вам нравится, так и поступайте. Единственное правило — *consistency*, то есть в рамках одного проекта всегда действуйте только по одному выбранному правилу.

Comment: @0andriy нет, это не дискуссия о вкусе. Значит вы не внимательно прочитали  вопрос (или вообще его не читали)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Понял. Значит лучше перебздеть, чем недобздеть :)))))

Comment: Читал и понял что вы хотите сделать, и это спор о вкусах. Посмотрите на большие проекты, почему у них всё хорошо при другом подходе? В чём принципиальная (с технической т.з.) разница? Да ни в чём.

Comment: ruSO — открытая площадка, вы же пишите здесь, почему другие не могут? К чему все эти персональные атаки?

Comment: Я ещё раз перечитал вопрос, у меня возник встречный: что вы подразумеваете под _Важно чтобы коммиты отображались именно на тех ветках, где были сделаны, а не шли в одной ветке, как прямая дорога._? Вы храните все ветки даже после слияния?!

Comment: @0andriy, подразумевается, что должен быть создан merge-commit

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, это ну совсем неочевидно из текста. _отображались иммено на тех ветках_ — как-то не вписывается в логику.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению ваша ссылка «тут» недоступна из моего региона, а ваше цитат не полная.

git может проводить слияние тремя способами:

- `--ff` — (по умолчанию) попытаться выполнить перемотку (fast forward), если не удалось, то создать коммит слияния.
- `--no-ff` — всегда создавать коммит слияния.
- `--ff-only` — попытаться выполнить перемотку, если не удалось, завершить ошибкой.

Подробности: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---ff

Перемотка может быть выполнена только если ветка, в которую идёт слияние стоит на том коммите, который есть во вливаемой ветке (как правило это точка ветвления, но не обязательно).

Если после точки ветвления в обеих ветках есть свои коммиты (отсутствующие во второй), то будет создан коммит слияния. В этом случае совершенно не обязательно указывать параметр `--no-ff`. Но и мешать он не будет.

> А если я нахожусь на ветке `test1` сливаю себе `dev`, чтобы обновить данные, делаю ещё небольшую правку, коммит, пуш, а потом перехожу на `dev` и вливаю себе эту ветку `test1` то тоже уже не надо указывать флаг `--no-ff`?

Если после вливание `dev` в `test1` в ветке `dev` не было новых коммитов, то без указания `--no-ff` будет выполнена перемотка. Потому что коммит ветки `dev` находится в ветке `test1`, вы его сами влили. А так как вы ранее вливали `dev` в `test1`, то в истории коммиты из `test1` будут отображаться как будто они были сделаны в основной ветке, а коммиты из `dev` — как из ветки разработки. Тут настоятельно рекомендуется делать `--no-ff`.

Для того, чтоб не задумываться ставить `--no-ff` или нет, лучше всегда ставить. А чтоб не забывать, можно указать в настройках git, что по умолчанию нужно использовать `--no-ff`, а не `--ff`. Делается это командой `git config --add merge.ff false`

Подробности: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergeff